# VSCode Test Explorer not finding module despite PYTHONPATH defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

**EDIT**

Thanks the comment below, I've managed to get the command to work from the CLI. However, I'm still struggling to make it work using VSCode's test explorer.
Here's my current settings.json:

```json
{
    ...
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.cwd": "./data-quality/tests"
}
```

Thru the Python output on VSCode, I'm getting `modulenotfound` errors, as if the `PYTHONPATH` wasn't taken in account.

```bash
> /usr/local/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/unittest_discovery.py . *test*.py
cwd: ./data-quality/tests
[ERROR 2022-11-28 11:31:16.278]: Error discovering unittest tests:
 Failed to import test module: test_helpers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/b242pn/Documents/SOC/data-quality/data-quality/tests/test_helpers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helpers import group_columns_by_vendor_product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

=====================================================================

I've got a project with the following structure:

```
├── data-quality
│   ├── __pycache__
|   ├── helpers.py
│   └── tests
│       └── __pycache__
|       └── test_helpers.py
├── include
└── share
```

I'm currently in `tests`, trying to use a module in its parent folder, `data-quality`. I've heard that to use them in a testing context, it is important to use absolute imports, so I tried doing so:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from helpers import group_columns_by_vendor_product
import unittest
...
```

However, whenever I use python to discover these tests, I get a modulenotfound error:

```bash
 python3 -m unittest discover -v -s data-quality/tests -p 'test_*.py'
======================================================================
ERROR: test_helpers (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_helpers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "data-quality/tests/test_helpers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from helpers import group_columns_by_vendor_product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

Am I missing something?

TIA

P.S: I noticed that the tests run when I run the command locally, and inside of the data-quality folder, but not above:

```bash
python3 -m unittest discover -v -s . -p 'test_*.py'
test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior (test_helpers.TestGroupColumnsByVendorProduct) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior (test_helpers.TestGroupColumnsByVendorProduct)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b242pn/Documents/SOC/data-quality/data-quality/tests/test_helpers.py", line 54, in test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior
    self.assertEqual([("Microsoft", "Microsoft Windows")], result)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')] != []

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')

- [('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')]
+ []

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

python3 -m unittest discover -v -s ./tests -p 'test_*.py'
test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior (test_helpers.TestGroupColumnsByVendorProduct) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior (test_helpers.TestGroupColumnsByVendorProduct)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b242pn/Documents/SOC/data-quality/data-quality/tests/test_helpers.py", line 54, in test_group_columns_by_vendor_product_normal_behavior
    self.assertEqual([("Microsoft", "Microsoft Windows")], result)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')] != []

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')

- [('Microsoft', 'Microsoft Windows')]
+ []

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

Comment: Changing sys.path in your script, like `sys.path.append('../')`, is a bad idea. Better change it in your environment, by setting the PYTHONPATH variable. In this case, set it to the full path to the data-quality directory. From a terminal, use `export PYTHONPATH=/Users/b242pn/Documents/SOC/data-quality/data-quality`. Then run as normal (in the same terminal), but remove the `sys.path` part. This way, you can run the line `from helpers import group_columns_by_vendor_product` anywhere, since the parent directory is now on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @9769953! The command seems to work in the terminal, but when using VSCode's test explorer, I get the same issue (modulenotfound error)

Comment: For VSCode, you probably need to set environment variables somewhere in its settings. A search for "set pythonpath in vscode" might get you there.

Comment: Vscode takes the open folder as the workspace, please configure the cwd variable or change the open folder or file structure.